# Create dynamic variables based on categories taken from the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried to create form where there are any options generate from database. Each type of product will generate different option.
For example:

Product A , there will be option: upgrade ram and upgrade core. And the choice available is different between another product.

But on the product B, there will be no option.

I've succeeded displaying those options on my form, but I can't continue to save it to the database. Because I am confused to determine the variable that will use to input to database (on the picture below variable "var"). What is the next step.
[image]

my table database:

[image]

[image]

here is my view

```html
<?php foreach($configcat->result_array() as $row):
    $idcat = $row['id_category'];
    $category =$row['name'];  
?>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label><?php echo htmlentities($category, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></label>
<select name="<?php echo htmlentities("conf".$idcat, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<?php
foreach ($configOption->result_array() as $option){
    $idCatO = $option['id_category'];
    $detail = htmlentities($option['detail_config'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    if ($idCatO == $idcat){
 echo "<option value=\"$detail\">$detail</option>";
    }
} ?>
</select> 
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this my controller:

```html
$hostname = $this->input->post("hostname");
$rootPassword = $this->input->post("rootPassword");
$hitung = $this->m_user->hitungRow();
$idUser= $this->session->userdata('id_user');
$timeStamp = sha1(date('Y-m-d'));
if ($hitung > 0){
    for ($x=1; $x <= $hitung; $x++){
 $var1 = "conf".$x;
 $var= $this->input->post($var1); 
    }
}
//input to database????
```

Comment: please expand on "Because I am confused to determine the variable is." your problem statement isn't very clear. what is the current output and what are you expecting (*important*)?

Comment: @Alex thanks for answering my question. I've made improvement to my question.
I've succeded to save my option value on variabel $var inside looping "for". How to insert it into database column, when it variable change different product. If there is no option before, that column on database doesnt exists. How the simple logic for my case above. thanks

Comment: First of all make all fetched data in same array and that will pass that array  to Model. Did you put all the fetched data into single array variable